# How to show username on dropdown button using React-Bootstrap and EJS?

Tags: express, ejs, react-bootstrap

I would like to show username on dropdown button after users log in to my site. But, how is it done using React-Bootstrap?

My code for the dropdown button looks like this.

```
<DropdownButton title="Dropdown" id="bg-nested-dropdown">
  <MenuItem eventKey="1">Account</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem eventKey="2">Log Out</MenuItem>
</DropdownButton>
```

I want to change the title to username so that he/she can confirm that they actually logged in by seeing their username on the dropdown button.

I can retrieve username easily like this using EJS.

```
<% if (!user) { %>
  some text
<% } else { %>
  <%= user.username %>
<% } %>
```

But, I want to show the username(`user.username`) on the dropdown button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
<DropdownButton title="Dropdown" id="bg-nested-dropdown">
  <MenuItem eventKey="1">Account</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem eventKey="2">Log Out</MenuItem>
  { user ? <MenuItem eventKey="x">{ user.username }</MenuItem> : <MenuItem eventKey="y">Some text</MenuItem> }
</DropdownButton>
```

Comment: It says user is not defined. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you were using EJS, where would you have taken the `user` variable from? Use the same in your react component.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm still struggling to solve this issue. I've set user variable in EJS like this. router.get("/", function(req, res) { res.render("Index", { user: req.user }); I can see the variable is set properly because, without the line "{ user ? <MenuItem eventKey......", it can return the username wherever on the index page except where the React-Bootstrap components are used, in this case DropdownButton.

Answer (score 0):

Gilad's answer makes sense to me, but I've never tried this myself.

Maybe some things to consider:

- are you keeping track of state anywhere and can you put your user object into state *outside* of this react button?
- have you tried this.user?
- have you tried creating an EJS element (like a < p >) with the username and telling React to load that if it exists?

none of these may do it, but hey. I'm going to be doing some work like this in next few days and will update if I figure out something.

Comment: I'm keeping track of state in `user`, and yes I can use this `user` anywhere outside react button. I've tried this.user, but not working. I've tried creating an  EJS element with the username and it works anywhere except where the React button is. React returns a message saying "user is not defined". If I could pass the user variable to React, this problem would be solved. I appreciate any update from you. Thank you.

Comment: ok I mean, if you can save the user object in state, then from inside your React component, you typically just need to do a

    this.state.user.username

If you've saved your user into state with getInitiatState() = > { user: user } or what have you

Comment: Oh, excuse my lack of knowledge on React, but I think getInitialState is used only when you are doing client side. If I can not retrieve data by `{ user ? <MenuItem eventkey="x"........`, I don't think that will work. I need to get data into React when doing server-side rendering. If you are curious, I posted another question related on this matter on Stack Overflow titled as "How to get data into React when doing server-side rendering?". I posted all the code for server side there, so if you find anything wrong, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use `<Dropdown/>` instead of `<DropdownButton/>`

Example:

```
<Dropdown id="language-selector-in-header">
    <Dropdown.Toggle>
      <i className={iconClass}></i> Some text or other html elements
    </Dropdown.Toggle>
    <Dropdown.Menu>
      <MenuItem eventKey="en"><i className="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></i> English</MenuItem>
    </Dropdown.Menu>
  </Dropdown>
```